# View resolution definition

Tags: sql

I am currently studying up for an exam and one of the past paper questions is on view resolution. After having a Google around I have only made myself more confused on what exactly it is.

Sadly our lecture slides don't cover the subject in great detail. From what I understand it where the view definition is combined with a query. So for example you could select a view from within the view you are defining and it will run as if it was a normal query.

So where redandlondon is defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW redandlondon (pno, pname, mass)
AS SELECT pno, pname, weight * 2.2
FROM p
WHERE city = 'London';
```

Both the following will result in the same output

```
SELECT pname, mass
FROM redandlondon
ORDER BY pname;

SELECT pname, weight * 2.2
FROM p
WHERE city = ‘London’
ORDER BY pname;
```

Any help where I am wrong would be greatly appreciated and perhaps a simpler definition.

Thanks

Comment: How can the results be the same?   You have an additional constraint (colour = 'Red') in one case, and not the other's view.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Ah yeah sorry about that. Was meant to take that bit out. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables and Views both have definitions such as the columns of the table, or the columns in a view. All columns have given data types.

Tables hold row data for a given set of columns spread across the physical pages stored on a disk.

Views have definitions similar to tables. However, they do not hold row data. The data found in a view is populated by an underlying query that is reading from tables that hold row data.

When you read from a view, or join a view to an existing query the SQL server will then execute the query in the view and join it to your data set. When it does that, that would be view resolution.

Answer (score 0):

All data where city='London' are having red colors.

Comment: Hi @Amirreza Keshavarz. Thanks for answering!.

 Ignoring the color = 'Red' bit which I have since edited out (Sorry about that). Is my understanding of view resolution correct?